# point-in-polygon, simple 4 vertex polygon, no external libraries

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting things on a map with matplot lib and have an atlas of coordinates, I have a 4 vertex set of points that define a boundary on the map, I want to clear all entries in my atlas that don't fall within that boundary.

I've been trying the matplotlib path with .contains_points however that doesn't appear to working and the output plotted map has some points removed but not all that is outside the boundry.

My atlas data contains sightings of flora/fauna for a particular geographical area,

```
border= [(-35.2825, 149.108), (-35.2873, 149.118), (-35.2714, 149.118), (-35.2758, 149.127)]
border_path= Path(border, codes=None, closed=True)

# Atlas data is defined in another part. contains [name, lat, lon]
for n, i in enumerate(atlas_data):
    lat_lon = (i[1], i[2])

    if not border_path.contains_points([lat_lon], transform=None):
        del atlas_data[n]
```

Comment: The problem might be that you are modifying the list while iterating over it - try copying the in-bounds points to a separate list and plotting this in-bounds list.

Comment: Yes I’m sure that’s the cause of the symptoms you describe - every time a point is deleted, the following point is skipped because it has moved into the position of the deleted point, so it is not checked.

Comment: You ahouls give spacejunkee a hand, he’s struggling to overlay points on the map see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50544794/placing-coordinates-on-a-map-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but this should work if you then use inboundspoints to plot points instead of atlas_data - note the contains_points if statement doesn’t have `not` any more:

```
border= [(-35.2825, 149.108), (-35.2873, 149.118), (-35.2714, 149.118), (-35.2758, 149.127)]
border_path= Path(border, codes=None, closed=True)
inboundspoints = []
# Atlas data is defined in another part. contains [name, lat, lon]
for n, i in enumerate(atlas_data):
    lat_lon = (i[1], i[2])

    if border_path.contains_points([lat_lon], transform=None):
        inboundspoints.append( atlas_data[n] )
```

Comment: It indeed worked!, I also has to remove codes=None as it would then only use the first 3 points as a polygon :/

Turns out I was having this issue in other areas, deleting while looping rather than creating another dictionary. I had initially thought that it was more messy to create extra variables but that ended up causing more issues.

Thank you very much, I had spent hours pouring over point-in-polygon problems/algorithms,